# Decision Tree Analysis Using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have three rasters that have been reclassified into 5 classes each. I would like to use decision tree analysis, using the classes in the 3 rasters to come up with a final raster that has 5 classes, developed by using the classes in the 3 rasters as criteria.

How can I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q& A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: Don't know about arcmap, but if you have access to R, you can use `CART` library to use binary trees and the `raster` and `rgdal` libraries to load and manipulate raster data.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that am not familiar with R.

Comment: Use combine, it will give you unique combinations of all three that you can reclassify into five groups

Comment: Can you add more info to your question? It is not clear whether you already have a decision tree model and would like to implement it in ArcMap to process your rasterm or whether you are looking for ArcMap to build the tree for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the 3rd party Marine Geospatial Ecology Tools for ArcGIS.  It will perform CART and also has a tool for creating a raster from a decision tree.